# How to encrypt API input and output in angular?

Tags: angular, encryption, mean-stack, public-key-encryption

I have a meanstack application, in which we are using REST API to get data from node server to angular client. when I make an API call, in the network tab of the browser's developer tools, we can see the API input and output as plain text. We thought of using a symmetric/asymmetric key encryption but the encryption key will be exposed as we've to store the keys in the client side only. Is there any better approach to solve this problem?? 
Our application is secured with an SSL certificate.

For example, I'm calling the getUserInfo API in one of the webpages. It will return the user's Id, role, department and other details. I want to hide those details getting displayed to the users.  I don't want to display the user's ID, department and some other details getting displayed to the end user. But I need those details for some of the actions in my application.
[image]

Comment: Who are you trying to hide the information from here? If you are trying to hide the information from other devices in the same network as the client or who may be able to intercept traffic between the client and the Node server (eg ISPs, routers, people on the same unsecured WiFi network as the client, etc), then you just need to access the API via SSL. If you are looking to hide it from the client, then you likely have an XY Problem - you cannot reliably hide data from the client that you need the client to use.

Comment: If you're trying to hide data that is present on the user's computer from the user themselves, then you have a design problem.

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelly, Luke,  I don't want to display the user's ID, department and some other details getting displayed to the end user. But I need those details for some of the actions in my application. I've updated the question with an image for better understanding. Thank you

Comment: Then your server should return anonymized tokens for these instead of the real information, and the actions should take those tokens instead. As others have pointed out, if you need to send the data to the client, the client will always be able to read it one way or another.

Comment: @VBC Your response further confirms my comment - you have a design problem.  If you don't want information visible on the front-end - **don't send it there!**

Comment: Yeah, you're essentially asking how to tell someone a secret without them knowing the secret.